# nginx: how to get a server for the case of no Host: header?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, nginx-config

I've got a special server {} block for the case of people who use an IP address in a host header (`server_name ~^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+;`) and that works fine. I'd like a different server block for one when no host header at all is provided. I've been testing with:

```
telnet localhost 80
GET /foobar HTTP/1.0
```

And I see from my logging (which has `"$http_host"` in the log_format) this shows up as `"-"` (hyphen not underscore). But this server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        # hyphen not underscore
        server_name ~^-*$;

        root /var/www/no-host;
        default_type text/plain;
        index foo.ey
        location / {
                try_files $uri /foo.ey;
        }
}
```

Never gets used, the request instead goes to default which has `server_name _;` (underscore not hyphen).

My use case is similar to a domain parking site, I want a lot of hostnames to be handled, and all legit ones should be looked up in a database, but I want to screen certain illegitimate ones early.

Comment: Try `^$` to match an empty server name

Comment: I had that before I added in the `-*` in `^-*$`.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html Search for the word "empty"

Comment: `server_name "";`

Comment: That works. Thanks @Barmar.

Comment: @Barmar nice answer you got there https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087778, hope you don't mind.

Comment: I didn't answer because the question doesn't even belong on this site.

Comment: @Barmar Oh sry, I went a bit overboard coming from low-quality review queue here, to fix Cupcake quoting you. I didn't even consider that this doesn't belong here (based on the comments). But now with a proper looking answer, can't we just push it over to serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer is in the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html 
>   Search for the word "empty"
>
> **Fix:** `server_name "";`
>
> – [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)